# laravel 5.5 err_empty_response after execute method

Tags: php, laravel, apache, .htaccess, laravel-5.5

We write script that delete data from 8 tables in Mysql, in localhost we test this script and we have no problem with that, but when up the code on server , this script delete data but the execution time is too long and we faced the err_empty_response error page in chrome , please help us to increase the time of execution or other way that suitable for handle this problem
I use this code at first of my method:

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
```

and use this code in my htaccess:

```
php_flag opcache.enable Off
```

but these codes not work , we want to execute this script for thousands of records.
please help us thank you :)

Comment: It can be also out of memory.

Comment: share your code which gives you this error ?

Comment: my code has too much complexity, i thought this problem caused by memory or exe time

Comment: You need to optimize your query as well to take less time to delete

Comment: How did you solve the issue? I facing the same issue in local machine when doing some task taking around 1 hour to finish